# Консольный компилятор для Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, g++, mingw-w64

В Unix для компиляции одного файла можно использовать команды gcc/g++ , в Windows такого по умолчанию нет. Раньше я устанавливал то ли GCC для виндовс, то ли Mingw, и подобная команда появлялась. Сейчас установить это чудо не могу - на сайте mingw и mingw64 не могу найти бинарники для скачивания и установки.

Что мне установить, чтобы подобная команда появилась?

Вообще мне нужно просто компилировать отдельные файлы с программой на плюсах. Не хочется для каждой мелкой програмки создавать проект (это если использовать для этих целей Qt или студия), также не хочется пользоваться CodeBlocks (он решает эту проблему - компилировать отдельные файлы умеет, но у него есть другие проблемы, из-за которых я пытаюсь от него уйти).

Comment: У меня VC++ стоит, вполне компилирует в командной строке...

Comment: mingw входит в пакет msys2, можно скачать его: https://www.msys2.org

Comment: @Harry , а VC++ это что ? компонент студии? я просто загуглил, он меня перекинул на Visual C++... у меня стоит студия, возможно у меня уже есть VC++...

Comment: Бинарники MinGW-w64 лежат тут: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/

Comment: Если студия стоит - то у вас должны быть установлены и такие вещи как (перечисляю по своей установке) `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`,  `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`, `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019` и т.п. окна командной строки. В них все настроено для использования компиляции из командной строки. Я для себя немного пошаманил, чтоб там еще и Far запускался, и из него работаю :)

Answer (score 1):

[Пользуюсь Mingw в составе MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/)